Bad request: Authorization header is correct, but the token seems invalid
I am trying to practice langchain on google colab and by using the google flab model to do chaining and when i run the code I get this error Bad request: Authorization header is correct, but the token seems invalid.
after research and trying all the possible solutions like:

checking if the correct read/write permissions are set in huggingface.
generating a new token
clearing my cookies,cache and all

I have also attached a pic of the error
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1orB7jgp-1zOX7F3zbOXZ73qOqVg26ruD?usp=sharing
here i a link to the google collab notebook i used
pls help me!!!!!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

you should show minimal reproducible example which we could copy and test. Maybe this model can't be used with any of your token. Maybe you have to pay for access to model.

Oh my bad I have shared my notebook so that it help a bit

In a few simple steps:

Visit huggingface.co/settings/tokens and find your token.
Edit Access Token Permissions
Under Inference check box Make calls to the serverless Inference API.
Under Repos check box Write access to contents/settings of all repos under your personal namespace
Save and retry to run your code.


Hey Simas, I tried the exact method you have metioned. However I still get the same error. thank you so much for trying, I appreciate it. Let me know if there is any other way
